# Example of a second order differentail equation with finite explosion time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to give an explample of a second order differential equation with finite explosion time, i.e. there must exists $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $lim_{x\to t_0} x(t)=\pm \infty$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean a "real-live" example?

Comment: What are the restrictions, do you want to avoid a blow-up that is built-in, the equation itself having a singularity? You could, for instance, restrict the question to autonomous equations to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Work backwards! Start with a function that explodes in finite time (eg $x(t)=\tfrac{1}{x-1}$) and derive the equation describing that function.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $u''+u=0$ with non-zero initial condition has roots in forward and backwards direction. Thus $y(x)=1/u(x)$ will have poles. Now you only need to substitute $u$ by $y$ in the first equation.
$$
u'=-y^{-2}y'\\
u''=-y^{-2}y''+2y^{-3}y'^2\\
0=yy''-2y'^2-y^2
$$